# C# Unity: Scoring system by distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a game in unity and I need to set a scoring system based on the distance that the player traveled.

Example of what I want: when the player travel 100 pixels he get +1 in his score.

How to do that with C#?

Thanks

Comment: Save the original position in a variable, then use `Vector3.Distance(<original position variable>, <object's transform>.position)` to calculate the score.

Answer (score -1):

update function -> store and sum up the delta position from current and last frame from the playergameobject